# make categories editor unchangeble for my post_type

Tags: categories, editor

In  WP 4.2 project I added new post_type using register_post_type function and taxonomy using register_taxonomy function
and 2 categories using wp_insert_category function. That all works for me ok, but :
1) In list of these post_type there are only 2 fields visible "Title" and "Date".
But I would like also to see the rest fields Author, Categories , Tags, which are usually visible in posts list. How to make it?

2) For this post_type I would like to keep these 2 categories unchangeble, and actually to make 2 categories of this post_type view only, not to add/delete/modify
categories of this post_type. If there is way for this ?

Comment: When registering a new post type you can select which metaboxes you want it to show. See the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type - The argument you are looking for is called "supports".

Comment: You will use custom_post_type UI plugin

Answer (score 0):

gdaniel, thank you for your reply, but actually I mean different :
1) show missing fields in my  post_type listing

2) modify categories block, not to add/delete categories, but always show 2 existing categories, as they are constants for my post_type .